# How do I noConflict the requireJS require/define methods?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Looking for `requirejs.noConflict()`, or some way to remove the global footprint from the library. My use case is that I'm writing a widget to run in a 3rd party page which might already define `require` and `define` (with a previous version of requirejs or even another library entirely).

I've tried implementing this myself and it mostly works. For simplicity lets assume I do not restore original values, only remove the footprint. I do something like this in my data-main:

```
  var mycontext = requirejs.config({context : 'asdf', baseUrl : 'http://foo.com' });

  mycontext(['require','foo'], function (require, foo) {
        var f = require('foo');
  });

  // namespace cleanup
  window.requirejs = undefined;
  window.require = undefined;
  window.define = undefined;
```

The problem here is that the `f` value from `require('foo')` returns null, but only iff I do my namespace cleanup. This smells like a bug in requirejs, but I'm hoping there's an official no-conflict solution.

Hard to google this one due to all the jQuery related noConflict() questions.

Answer (score 0):

The RequireJS documentation [has a section on this](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-optimization.html) titled "*HOW CAN I PROVIDE A LIBRARY TO OTHERS THAT DOES NOT DEPEND ON REQUIREJS?*"

You can also have a look at [the example build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L429), which shows how `wrap` can be used.

A good example of how this works is the [Flight library](https://github.com/flightjs/flight).

By default the library uses AMD but there is a standalone version that wraps all the modules in an anonymous function and includes a tiny require/define API at the top (They use [their own build tool](https://github.com/flightjs/flight/blob/master/tools/standalone/build.js) for this). Source can be found [here](http://flightjs.github.io/release/latest/flight.js).

Note that for this to work all the modules will require IDs, but the r.js optimiser will handle that for you.

Using these techniques should allow you to leave any already defined require/define variables alone.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response --I had not seen that section. This is /almost/ exactly what I need.  I dynamically loading, so a r.js build option does not directly help, but I'll see about doing a build of my single bootstrap module, and dynamically loading form there.  Will let you know how that goes.

Comment: Well, your built file could still be loaded by a script loader, AMD or otherwise. It just would be treated as a normal JS file. If you want your code to still be consumable as an AMD module I would just allow it to use whatever require/define is present. It's up to the host page to use a compatible loader, not you. Be good to hear how it goes :)

Comment: After some research, I think I can safely say that the namespace attribute /only/ applies to r.js builds.  My use case is narrow enough that I think I'm better off rolling my own async AMD in my namespace.